# Export existing AWS Lambda and API Gateway to Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

How to export existing configured and tested infrastructure (including AWS Lambda functions, API Gateways, ElastiCache clusters, Cloudwatch rules) to Cloudformation template?

I know about Cloudformer tool, but it supports limited number of AWS services (Amazon VPC, DynamoDB, etc) and don't supports some of services which we use. Which tools and approaches can I use in my case for generating Cloudformation template?

Comment: Out of my experience it makes more sense to write everything from scratch without having a tool which is doing reverse engineering. For sure it means you need to spend much more time but on the other hand you are able to re-think (and understand) your whole infrastructure.

Comment: Yeah, the main cause why I'm looking for ways to export existing resources is to save time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Partial solution:** there is ability to export Lambda function to AWS SAM file

[image]

and then

[image]

We will get YAML file which describes your Lambda function as 'AWS::Serverless::Function'. But there are few things - we can't export Lambda aliases with such approach. Also that doesn't help with API Gateway exporting.

Comment: Not sure why but the Export Function option doesn't show on my function. It looks like I'll have to start from scratch too. I was hoping for a starting-template at least to try and save some time.

Answer (score 1):

[Former2](https://former2.com/) seems to be the most recent way to accomplish this, and supports most AWS services. AWS blog post on it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/).

> Former2 allows you to generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs from
> your existing resources within your AWS account. By making the
> relevant calls using the AWS JavaScript SDK, Former2 will scan across
> your infrastructure and present you with the list of resources for you
> to choose which to generate outputs for.

I just used it to export API Gateway and DynamoDB infra to a CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormer was built for this, however, I agree with @MaiKaY that you should rewrite everything. CloudFormer will create hard-links with IDs, where you have to replace these with references, add parameters and/or mappings. It can help you get started, so you know what you need in the template.

Comment: But CloudFormer don't supports Lambda functions and API Gateways

Comment: It can get you started at least. CloudFormation is worth it to learn and in the long run will save you more time. What we do is build a POC of what we want, then transfer that to CF and continue building off that template.