# Get AWS cloudformation for an existing lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to get the cloudformation for lambdas?
I know you can create AWS CloudFormation Templates from existing AWS Resources using [**CloudFormer**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html). And also, cloudformer is in beta mode (AWS CloudFormer 0.41 (Beta)) at the time I am asking this question. While following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html), I could not find a way to create cloudformation for my lambda

> I have ***selected everything*** while creating the cloudformation but
>   the template contains no lambdas.

Is it not supported or I am missing something? 
If it is not supported, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Seems like there is no way, however the below link helps me. Hope it is useful to you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906085/export-existing-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-to-cloudformation-template

Comment: There is no much of a secret for the lambda clouformation. I can share my yaml template here in the answers.

Comment: @Cleriston thanks, I was looking for a way to export cloudFormation template. The link in other comments demonstrate a way

Comment: The example has a config for AWS SAM, which is diff of CloudFormation. It has a different code management procedure. However, if it is what you are looking for, I dont have much to say. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the Lambda code to disk, you could use Rubycfn to create your Lambda function in CloudFormation.

`gem install rubycfn`

Save the file below to `example.rb` and run `rubycfn example.rb` to generate the CloudFormation.

```
def file_to_inline(filename)
  File.open(filename).read.split("\n")
end

resource :my_lambda_function,
         type: "AWS::Lambda::Function" do |r|
  r.property(:code) do
    {
      "ZipFile": file_to_inline("/path/to/lambda.py").fnjoin("\n")
    }
  end
  r.property(:role) { :your_lambda_role.ref(:arn) }
  r.property(:handler) { "index.lambda_handler" }
  r.property(:runtime) { "some_runtime" }
end
```